# How to process SIGTERM signal gracefully in Java?

Tags: java, process, daemon, sigterm, start-stop-daemon

Let's assume we have such a trivial daemon written in java:

```
public class Hellow {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
            // 1. do
            // 2. some
            // 3. important
            // 4. job
            // 5. sleep
        }

    }
}
```

and we daemonize it using `start-stop-daemon` which by default sends `SIGTERM` (TERM) signal on `--stop`

Let's suppose the current step performed is #2. And at this very moment we're sending TERM signal.

What happens is that the execution terminates immediately.

I've found that I can handle the signal event using `addShutdownHook()` but the thing is that it still interrupts the current execution and passes the control to handler:

```
public class Hellow {
    private static boolean shutdownFlag = false;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        registerShutdownHook();

        try {
            doProcessing();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    static private void doProcessing() throws InterruptedException {
        int i = 0;
        while(shutdownFlag == false) {
            i++;
            System.out.println("i:" + i);
            if(i == 5) {
                System.out.println("i is 5");
                System.exit(1); // for testing
            }

            System.out.println("Hello"); // It doesn't print after System.exit(1);

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    static public void setShutdownProcess() {
        shutdownFlag = true;
    }

    private static void registerShutdownHook() {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Tralala");
                Hellow.setShutdownProcess();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, my question is - is it possible to not interrupt the current execution but handle the `TERM` signal in a separated thread (?) so that I would able to set `shutdown_flag = True` so that loop in `main` would had a chance to stop gracefully?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I rewritten the `registerShutdownHook()` method and now it works as I wanted.

```
private static void registerShutdownHook() {
    final Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Tralala");
                Hellow.setShutdownProcess();
                mainThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }

        }
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SignalHandler. Please check out this example: https://dumpz.org/2707213/

It will catch up `INTERRUPTED` signal and unset `operating` flag, which in turn will allow app shutdown gracefully.

[image]

Comment: Yes, your solution works but at compile time the compiler swears that `SignalHandler` in the future does not work. I found another solution, but thanks)

Comment: @IslomkhodjaHamidullakhodjaev Would you share your solution? Kind regards