# Cloud Run graceful shutdown

Tags: java, kotlin, google-cloud-run

I am following up on:

- https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/graceful-shutdowns-cloud-run-deep-dive
- [How to process SIGTERM signal gracefully in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365753/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully-in-java)

I have a CloudRun service which is doing some `while` cycles which currently seem not to end after the CloudRun revision is replaced. I guess the CloudRun manager is waiting for the revision to gracefully end, which unfortunately does not happen.

I tried adding:

```kotlin
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()
```

And end the loops with this listener. Unfortunately there are two issues:

1. It is not possible to subscribe more shutdownHooks (each for one running loop) - getting errors of `Hook already running`. This is an implementation issue and I wonder if there is a different way to do this.
2. When I send the `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` to locally running service, it ends immediately and the shutdownHook is never called. This is  a logical issue and I am not sure if this is the way CloudRun ends the revisions - it seems not, otherwise the loops would be immediately ended like on my localhost.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47365753/18157

Comment: Thanks for linking a document I have already linked above.

Comment: What's your "while" and "running loop"? I don't understand your context, and your issue.